# How to store DateTime data and calculate it later? Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a beginner, and I'm trying to make something like a classic Tamagotchi game with a flower, where you need to water it once a day. I'm using "Water the flower" button as a main functionality. And to do that, I need to know when was the last time clicked to compare it with the current time.

I was hard trying to work with the `PlayerPrefs` and `DateTime` methods, but here is the problem — `DateTime` using longs, and `PlayerPrefs` using `int` or `strings`. I found the solution to convert `DateTime` into Binary and then to String, but Unity told me this thing:

> FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
> System.Number.StringToNumber (System.String str,
> System.Globalization.NumberStyles options, System.Number+NumberBuffer&
> number, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo info, System.Boolean
> parseDecimal) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
> System.Number.ParseInt64 (System.String value,
> System.Globalization.NumberStyles options,
> System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo numfmt) (at
> <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0) System.Int64.Parse
> (System.String s, System.IFormatProvider provider) (at
> <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0) System.Convert.ToInt64
> (System.String value) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
> HealthScript.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/HealthScript.cs:42)

Here is the entire code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class HealthScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int health = 100;
    public Slider slider;
    public int damage;
    public int waterTime;
    public bool isGoing = true;
    DateTime currentTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
    DateTime lastTimeClicked;

    //reseting the health every time button is clicked and saving the time of it
    public void buttonClicked()
    {
        health = 100;
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("Last Time Clicked", DateTime.UtcNow.ToBinary().ToString());
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        //connecting the health to the slider
        slider.value = health;
        //quit of the game
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            Application.Quit();
        }

        //calculating the difference between last click and actual time
        long temp = Convert.ToInt64(PlayerPrefs.GetString("Last Time Clicked"));
        lastTimeClicked = DateTime.FromBinary(temp);
        print("LastTimeClicked" + lastTimeClicked);

        TimeSpan difference = currentTime.Subtract(lastTimeClicked);
        print("Difference: " + difference);
    }
}
```

For now, I'm just trying to solve this issue to step forward to other things.
Could you please suggest the solution for the console log, or maybe a better way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Why not just save the `DateTime` as a `string`, skipping the `ToBinary`, then use `DateTime.Parse` to retrieve it?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. With this, could I make simple subtracting of two dates later? Like, while it set as a string or when it set as a DataTime?

Comment: To compare, you first convert the string to a DateTime with `DateTime.Parse(string)`, then you can compare those DateTime values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the way you store and retrieve the `DateTime` the rest of your logic should be fine. Try this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class HealthScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int health = 100;
    public Slider slider;
    public int damage;
    public int waterTime;
    public bool isGoing = true;
    DateTime currentTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
    DateTime lastTimeClicked;

    //reseting the health every time button is clicked and saving the time of it
    public void buttonClicked()
    {
        health = 100;
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("Last Time Clicked", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()); // you can add a formatter here if you want
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        //connecting the health to the slider
        slider.value = health;
        //quit of the game
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            Application.Quit();
        }

        //calculating the difference between last click and actual time
        lastTimeClicked = DateTime.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("Last Time Clicked"));
        print("LastTimeClicked" + lastTimeClicked);

        TimeSpan difference = currentTime.Subtract(lastTimeClicked);
        print("Difference: " + difference);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to log to the console, the command is `Debug.Log`, `Debug.LogWarning`, or `Debug.LogError`.

You'll need to make sure you have your console filters set to show whatever you're trying to print, too:

[image: Console filters]

Comment: Sorry, on "Console log" I've meant the text which Unity told me as an issue

Comment: @ValeriyKit - What are you putting into the PlayerPrefs?? I run your code and I can't trigger your error, but I don't have whatever you're using to put time into PlayerPrefs. My guess is you're maybe butchering it somehow and then it's failing to parse? Then maybe your `difference` is null and you're trying to print that. Also looks like maybe you edited your code after posting the error? Line 42 in the code you've posted doesn't correspond to a function, making it harder to debug for you.